# Assett Bundle from external program

Tags: c#, android

I need a way to build an asset Bundle with an external `.exe`. This `.exe` should use the path of the file to build an asset Bundle. Is there a way to do It?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: I try to search if There were some application that already do it, and I try to see Unity documetation about how an asset Bundle is built, but nothing explain if there's a way to do It in a different program

Comment: With an external exe? With a Windows program? External from what? And what do you mean with an asset bundle? And about which file are you talking?